# Running JAR in Console

Tags: java, windows

I have created program that takes input from `System.in` and output to `System.out`. I create the executable jar and I want to run it without entering `java -jar` in windows. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  The simplest way is to create a batch (`.bat` file) file that invokes it for you.  There are also a number of solutions out there that will create a Windows executable from a jar file.  Note: these programs don't compile the byte code, they just create an executable wrapper around the jar.  One option is [Jar2Exe](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/) but there are quite a few.  [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) is another option I have used before that works quite well.  Another advantage to a program like this is you can bundle all dependent jars into the same executable file as well.  Some google searching for "jar to exe" should find you one that works for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a .bat script that will start your jar.

Answer (score 0):

On windows a simple double-click on the jar file should open it if the environment is well set.

Answer (score 0):

You use the "start" command like "`C:\> start myJarFile.jar`".